# Run-Time Error 6: Overflow Excel 2010

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I have a report in excel that brings in data from Access 2010. When I run it, it gives me an overflow error at `numRecords = .Range(.Cells(2, 3), .Cells(2, 3).End(xlDown)).Count`.

```
Dim numRecords As Integer
    Dim row As Integer
    Dim numListed As Integer
    Dim col As Integer
    Dim deliveryMethod As String
    Dim col2 As Integer
    Dim numCol As Integer

With Worksheets("Raw Export")
    numRecords = .Range(.Cells(2, 3), .Cells(2, 3).End(xlDown)).Count
    numCol = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, 3).End(xlToRight)).Count
End With
```

I tried changing numRecords as Long but it just moved the error. Any tips would be great.

Comment: Any variable you use for rows should be a `Long`, not `Integer`. I don't know what you mean by "it just moved the error"?

Comment: @Rory - You should post this as the answer.

Comment: @JasonFaulkner Depends - OP claims to have already done this but only "moved" the error, so I'm waiting for clarification.

Comment: It gave me the error and hilighted a different line. I changed that variable to long, too, and it seems to be working.